# Define New Arithmetic Operation in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I've created a simple class.

```
class Zoo {
  public int lionCount;
  public int cheetahCount;
  Zoo(lions, cheetahs) { 
    lionCount = lions;
    cheetahCount = cheetahs;
  }
}
```

Now let's say I have 2 zoos.

```
Zoo zoo1 = new Zoo(1,2);
Zoo zoo2 = new Zoo(3,5);
```

Is it possible to define arithmetic operation for this class, such that...

```
Zoo zoo3 = zoo1 + zoo2; //makes a zoo with 4 lions and 7 cheetahs
Zoo zoo4 = zoo1 * zoo2; // makes a zoo with 3 lions and 10 cheetahs
```

In other words, how can I define custom arithmetic operations for a C# class?

Comment: Sounds like an extension method to overload the + operator when two objects typeof(Zoo)?

Comment: @gwilliams No, not an extension method, an operator overload.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can using operator overloading

```
class Zoo 
{
  public int lionCount;
  public int cheetahCount;

  Zoo(int lions, int cheetahs) 
  { 
    lionCount = lions;
    cheetahCount = cheetahs;
  }

  public static Zoo operator +(Zoo z1, Zoo z2) 
  {
    return new Zoo(z1.lionCount + z2.lionCount, z1.cheetahCount + z2.cheetahCount);
  }
}
```

The other operators are handle pretty much the same way ;-)

For more information about it check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Operator overloading can be done like this:

```
   public static Zoo operator +(Zoo z1, Zoo z2) 
   {
      return new Zoo(z1.lionCount + z2.lionCount, z1.cheetahCount + z2.cheetahCount);
   }
```

I think you can figure out the other operators yourself. For more information see this tutorial: [link to tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx)

**Note:** the operator must be placed within the class itself (`Zoo` class in this case)

Comment: Pretty straight forward to me, but I will add that hehe